# Growing Code Review, One Idea... :-)

Tags: discussion

Really like the idea of a Stack Exchange site for peer reviewed code, which leads me to my question.

**Is there any reason why code "reviewers" can't review code on other SE sites, post a comment suggesting that the code, or a segment of the code be cross posted (with a link to the cross post in the original questions description) -- and then peer reviewed on SE.CodeReview?**

Seems like it'd might solve problems related to traffic, content, and quality.

In terms of reviewers, guessing that's super easy to solve once there's enough traffic and quality content being posted. It's possible I could figure out a way to "ping" SE users that would be "experts" on a given code base without being spam like, or off-topic on another SE site.

So, any feedback on this idea? I'd be happy to give it a try, and aim to find and post 5 comments a day on SE sites with code that lends itself to peer review.

Also, if such a meta.SE.CodeReview question on the scope and use of the site doesn't exist, that'd be a huge help in converting content and users to the site.

---

**UPDATE (1):** Based on Jeff's response below, I'm moving forward with this approach, but I would welcome any and all feedback or suggestions. I've also posted a question related to this question on Programmers.SE:
[Suggestions for finding code to review](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62449/suggestions-for-finding-code-to-review)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, you can, as long as people are clear what code review is for -- essentially, *functioning, working code* that needs to be improved in some subjective, perhaps even aesthetic, way.

If the code is in any way broken or does not work, that is not the purpose of Code Review.

Comment: +1 @Jeff Atwood: Right, though one would hope that a huge percent of questions with an excepted answer on another SE site end up with working code; which then might lend itself to idiomatic alignment, code refactoring, editorial stylization, etc. Anyway very glad to hear that in concept the idea is "okay." Guess at this point the best thing is to just give it a go...  :-) ...Cheers!!